# Web site doesn't give me json file

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests, html-parsing

I have a task to write a parser for some sites(csgofast ,loot.run, upx). I need to get data from crash game (final score)  but there is no suitable json packets in network part of browsers. [image: In the right side of network it's information for advertisment]

Comment: Check if the site provides an API, and if not, you will have to scrape data using an html parser. Note that it may be against the terms of use of the site and be a legal liability.